# Generating A Confidence Interval For A Simulation

Tags: probability, statistics

so I ran a simulation of 3 conditions 1,000,000 times:

1. A is met - 499674
2. B is met - 500376
3. C is met - 25004

So I know that A should occur about %49.967 of the time.

I also know that B should occur about %50.0376 of the time

Further more, I know both should occur at the same time about %25.004 of the time.

Knowing this, how do I find the confidence intervals for these items?

**Additionally, would these events would be independent, because p(A) & p(B) together is about p(A*B) which would signify independence?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confidence interval depends on the sample size ... and with 1,000,000 cases, the confidence interval will be very small: the margin of error for a $95$% confidence interval is only about $0.1$%, or $1,000$. That is, there is a $95$% chance that $P(A)$ is between $49.867$% and $50.067$%

And yes, I would say you have excellent reasons to believe $A$ and $B$ are independent given how close $P(A \cap B)$ is to $P(A) \cdot P(B)$